# vagrant add in yosemite

Tags: proxy, vagrant, osx-yosemite

I have installed vagrant and virtual box.I am running this command in Yosemite:

```
 vagrant box add lucid32 http://files.vagrantup.com/lucid32.box
```

The output is:

```
==> box: Box file was not detected as metadata. Adding it directly...
==> box: Adding box 'lucid32' (v0) for provider: 
    box: Downloading: http://files.vagrantup.com/lucid32.box
An error occurred while downloading the remote file. The error
message, if any, is reproduced below. Please fix this error and try
again.

Empty reply from server
```

I am running it behind a proxy server. This is my Vagrantfile:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  if Vagrant.has_plugin?("vagrant-proxyconf")
    config.proxy.http     = "http://10.3.100.207:8080"
    config.proxy.https    = "http://10.3.100.207:8080"
    config.proxy.no_proxy = "localhost,127.0.0.1"
  end
end
```

What's going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

`vagrant box add` does not read from Vagrantfile so it will not know about your Proxy configuration.

The best/easiest would be to download the file separately, directly from your browser from http://files.vagrantup.com/lucid32.box and then do `vagrant box add lucid32 <path to the downloaded box file>` and it will load the box into the vagrant box folder and then you can run the VM from the installed box.